# Make mobile image fullscreen on click for zom

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, zooming, pinchzoom

I want to implement a zoom feature for my mobile website images. Every website I've seen does this by making the image full screen when clicked on, which then lets the user pinch and zoom.

My website has a non scalable view port so I can't just have them zoom in on the actual website, I need to bring up the image they pressed on.

Is there a javascript plug in for this or should I try implementing this myself somehow?

Answer (score 1):

My way to do this is using this is using `addClass` and `removeClass`
https://jsfiddle.net/moongod101/5u775ges/
and a little bit of css `transition`

Answer (score 0):

More better using ToggleClass.

If you want use nice effect add transition.

JQUERY

```
$(function () {

    $('.small').click(function(){
        $('.small').toggleClass('full');
      $('body').toggleClass('dark')
  })

);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tndf33wL/)